# Exchange 2010 Powershell + C#: how to do WHERE query

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I'm using the exchange powershell in C# like this:

```
public PowershellResult GetSendAsPermissions(string TargetIdentity)
    {
        string CommandName = "get-adpermission";

        Command cmd1 = new Command(CommandName);
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("Identity", TargetIdentity);
        if (powershell.DomainController.Length > 0)
        {
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("DomainController", powershell.DomainController);
        }

        List<Command> commands = new List<Command>();
        commands.Add(cmd1);
        string errorMessages = string.Empty;
        Collection<PSObject> commandResults = powershell.ExecutePowershellCommand(commands, out errorMessages);


        PowershellResult psr = null;

        if (errorMessages.Length == 0)
        {
            psr = new PowershellResult(true, "Successfully managed SendAs permission.", 0);
        }
        else
        {
            psr = new PowershellResult(false, string.Format("Error managing SendAs permission: {0}", errorMessages), 0);
        }
        return psr;
    }

public Collection<PSObject> ExecutePowershellCommand(List<Command> commands, out string errorMessages)
    {
        errorMessages = "";
        this.ps.Commands.Clear();
        ps.Streams.Error.Clear();
        if (commands != null)
        {
            foreach (Command cmd in commands)
            {
                this.ps.Commands.AddCommand(cmd);
            }
            Collection<PSObject> ret = null;
            try
            {
                ret = this.ps.Invoke();
                if (this.ps.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
                {
                    StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (ErrorRecord err in this.ps.Streams.Error)
                    {
                        if (err.Exception.Message != null)
                        {
                            stb.AppendLine(err.Exception.Message);
                        }
                    }
                    errorMessages = stb.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();
                if (ex.Message != null)
                {
                    stb.Append(ex.Message);
                }
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    if (ex.InnerException.Message != null)
                    {
                        stb.Append(string.Format(" {0}", ex.InnerException));
                    }
                }
                errorMessages = stb.ToString().Trim();
            }

            return ret;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now I want to to add a "where" clause to the get-adpermission command like this:

```
Get-ADPermission | where {($_.ExtendedRights -like “*Send-As*”) -and ($_.IsInherited -eq $false) -and -not ($_.User -like “NT AUTHORITY\SELF”)}
```

I have absolutely no idea where to put the where clause or how to define those arguments in curly brackets. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see

```
 Collection<PSObject> commandResults = powershell.ExecutePowershellCommand(commands, out errorMessages);
```

but nothing is done with `commandResults` - they're not passed back to the caller.

What it looks like you'll need is something like

```
 var filteredResults = commandResults.Where(cr =>    
       (((string)cr.Properties["ExtendedRights"].Value).Contains("Send-As")) && 
       (((bool)cr.Properties["IsInherited"].Value) == false) &&
       (((string)cr.Properties["User"].Value) == "NT AUTHORITY\\SELF"))
```

That will (hopefully) get you a filtered list of `comandResults` with just the items you need. You'll want to pass that back to the caller somehow, or do something else with them.

Comment: The thing is that "Value" is merely of the type "object" so it doesnt have the method "Contains" on it...

Comment: Still some exceptions like PSObject cant be cast to string, guess there's a lot of casting and checking to do...

Comment: Sounds like you're in a better place to check that than me! Hopefully my answer has given you some hints, though...